# Recognize more than one character

Tags: java

I'm very new to coding and can't seem to figure out how to get this to print the bake name I know its because its trying to recognize a singular character but I don't know how to make it recognize more than one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int ingredients = 5+4+9+8+201+200+202+2+1+203;
    char bake;

    if (ingredients >= 835) {
        bake = 'Cookies';
    } else if (ingredients >= 80) {
        bake = 'C';
    } else if (ingredients >= 70) {
        bake = 'B';
    } else if (ingredients >= 60) {
        bake = 'D';
    } else {
        bake = 'W';
    }
    System.out.println("You can make " + bake);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Java` you distinguish between `char` and `String`

- `char` is one character, between simple quotes, like `'a'`
- `String` is a 1-to-multiple character suite, between double quotes, like `"Cookies"`

To hold `Cookies` you need a `String`

```
int ingredients = 5+4+9+8+201+200+202+2+1+203;
String bake;

if (ingredients >= 835) {
    bake = "Cookies";
} else if (ingredients >= 80) {
    bake = "C";
} else if (ingredients >= 70) {
    bake = "B";
} else if (ingredients >= 60) {
    bake = "D";
} else {
    bake = "W";
}
System.out.println("You can make " + bake);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `String` instead of `char` for the variable, `bake` e.g.

```
String bake = "some value";
```

Data type `char` is meant to hold a single character. To hold multiple characters you need to use data type `String`.

Comment: It's good to start the answer summarising the main problem. However, you should also write some explanation with examples. It's never late on SO to edit and improve your answer.

Comment: Looks better now. Keep it up!